# como hacer que un input apartir de 3 caracteres me vaya buscando coincidencias en la base de datos

Tags: angularjs

Ya tengo la conexión a la BD, en el `div` llamo a la base de datos pero trae como 16000 registro por lo cual no los puedo mostrar en un select, entonces se me ocurrió que desde el `input` despues de poner 3 caracteres empiece a buscar coincidencias, ¿alguna sugerencia?.

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-init="GetArticulos()">

     <input type="search"class="form-control" placeholder="Coloca el codigo de producto" ng-model="articulo in articulos"/>
     <select ng-model="articuloseleccionado" class="form-control"  data-content="Seleccione un articulo" placeholder="Seleccione un articulo">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un Articulo</option>
         <option ng-repeat="articulo in articulos " value="">{{tamano.ListaProductos}}</option>
     </select>

 </div>
```

Comment: quieres que empiece a buscar las coinicidencias en el select, o quieres buscar coincidencias en la base de datos?

Comment: no sería mejor listar esos registros en una tabla (`<table>`) y desde ahi insertar un `input` en el encabezado de la tabla para buscar coincidencias?

Comment: Encontre esta respuesta que tal vez pueda ayudarte, La mejor respuesta es un codigo que filtra el select conforme ingresas caracteres, tal vez puedas adaptarlo a tu codigo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Usa ajax de la siguiente forma:

```
var inputBusqueda = document.getElementById("inputBusuqeda");
inputBusqueda.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
     if(inputBusqueda.value.length > 3){
          //Llamada ajax
     }else{
          //Limpias la tabla donde muestras resultados
     }
});
```

Comment: 0
votar en contra
accept
Muchas gracias montes, pero no quiero mostrar una tabla, quiero hacer como un input predictivo, después de 3 caracteres me traiga coincidencias que encue tre en la base tendrás alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en el ejemplo suministrado por el usuario "handtrix" en jsfiddle y con unas pequeñas modificaciones para adaptarlo a tu necesidad puedes utilizar el siguiente código como solución a tu problema:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
      minLength:3,
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {
            
            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
            suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);
            
            // JSONP Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                response(data[1]);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />
```

La solución consiste en utilizar la librería de Jquery para contar con el módulo de autocompletado que ofrece su UI (jqueryui) el cual te permite realizar un autocompletado bien sea proveniente de un "json" (recomendado), una resultado de query a alguna base de datos o sencillamente "texto" colocado por tí dentro del documento fuente (no recomendado).

Para lograr que sea a partir de 3 caracteres tienes el parametro configurable denominado **minlenght** de la siguiente forma: `minLength:3` dentro de la función de autocompletado como lo muestra el snippet suministrado anteriormente.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo.

**Observación:** En el caso de la adaptación que realicé el plugin de autocompletado de jquery se referencia en el código fuente de jquery suministrado en línea pero también puedes descargarlo para colocarlo "localmente" en tu proyecto de la página oficial: [jqueryui](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)

**Fuente:** [ejemplo de autocompletado del usuario handtrix](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/)